# Javascript: How to assign result of asynchronous call

Tags: javascript, sqlite, asynchronous

So I'm having a really hard time with this.
I'm working on this school project where I have to develop a chat app, where the images of the messages(posts) and the user picture must be fetched through an API, and then saved and stored on the device and loaded from there after the first request.

I've implemented the chat page following the model/view/controller paradigm, my problem is that all posts are save before the user image is assigned to the post.

[Log's screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eY5Y9.png)

I've tried to use a callback function but it didn't quite work.
What can I do?

```
class ModelChannel {
  constructor() {

    this._posts = []

  }

  savePosts = (response) => {
    var json = JSON.parse(response);
    var post_list = json.posts;

    post_list.forEach(element => {
      var post = {
        uid: element.uid,
        name: element.name,
        pversion: element.pversion,
        pid: element.pid,
        type: element.type,
        content: element.content,
        lat: element.lat,
        lon: element.lon,

        profileImage: this.getProfileImage(sid, element.uid, element, (response) => {
          element.profileImage = response
          console.log("Callback getProfileImage");
          console.log("element.profile: " + element.profileImage);
        }),

      }

      //this.profileImage = this.getProfileImage(sid, element.uid, element)

      this._posts.push(post)
    });

    this.onPostListChanged(this._posts)

    console.log("All posts save into model");
    console.log(this._posts);
  }

  getPosts = (channelName) => {
    comunicationController.getChannel(sid, channelName, (response) => {
      console.log("Call %22getChannel%22 succeded");

      //salva nome canale
      this.savePosts(response)
    })
  }


  getProfileImage = (sid, uid, post, callback) => {
    var profileDB
    databaseHandler.getProfile(uid, (response) => {
      profileDB = JSON.parse(response);

      // if ( profileDB.pversion >= post.pversion){
      if (profileDB != null && profileDB.pversion >= post.pversion) {
        console.log("Profile of " + post.name + " loaded from database");

        //return profileDB.picture
        callback(profileDB.picture)
      } else {
        comunicationController.getUserPicture(sid, uid, (response) => {
          var json = JSON.parse(response);
          var picture = json.picture;

          databaseHandler.saveProfileImage(response)

          //return picture
          callback(picture)
        })
      }
    })

  }

  bindOnPostListChanged(callback) {
    this.onPostListChanged = callback
  }
}
```

Comment: Which function in the posted code do you expect to be invoked before which function, but it isn't?

Comment: GetProfile() and its logs should fire before the log of "all post saved in the model"

Comment: It looks like `databaseHandler.getProfile` is an asynchronous function which calls the callback you provided when it's finished. This means that when you're calling `getProfileImage()` - the JS invokes `databaseHandler.getProfile()` and then moves on to the next line before it actually completes "getting the profile". The callback is called at a later time, AFTER the browser finishes going through the reset of the JS in its path (which includes your `All posts save into model` log)

Comment: In other words, the posts have not yet been loaded at the time your `All posts save into model` is reached. To solve this you would need to re-organize the code a bit. If this `databaseHandler.getProfile()` thing supports Promises then it may be possible to simplify the flow using the `async` and `await` keywords, but these keywords hide away some details about how JS behaves internally that it's worthwhile to actually understand...

Comment: Refactored the code with promises, now everything is working fine